# How to save IP of user after submitting the django custom form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, ip

I wrote my own form for editing of profile and need to save ip of user, who edit profile, but not really understand how to do this. I know, that ip we can get from `request.META['REMORE_ADDR']` but where to put this and how to save to my db... Will be very glad if you could help.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   date_of_birth = models.DateField()
   biography = models.TextField()
   contacts = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class UserEditProfile(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField( max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField( max_length=30)
    date_of_birth = 
    forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(years=BIRTH_YEAR_CHOICES))
    biography = forms.Textarea()
    contacts = forms.CharField()


    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(UserEditProfile, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.fields['first_name'].initial = self.instance.first_name
        self.fields['last_name'].initial = self.instance.last_name
        self.fields['date_of_birth'].initial = 
        self.instance.date_of_birth
        self.fields['biography'].initial = self.instance.biography
        self.fields['contacts'].initial = self.instance.contacts


        self.fields.keyOrder = [
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'date_of_birth',
            'biography',
            'contacts'
            ]

    def save(self, *args, **kw):
        super(UserEditProfile, self).save(*args, **kw)
        self.instance.first_name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        self.instance.last_name = self.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        self.instance.date_of_birth = 
        self.cleaned_data.get('date_of_birth')
        self.instance.biography = self.cleaned_data.get('biography')
        self.instance.contacts = self.cleaned_data.get('contacts')
        self.instance.save()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'date_of_birth',
            'biography',
            'contacts'
        )
        exclude = ['user', 'ip_address']
```

view.py

```
def edit_profile(request):
    user = Profile.objects.get(id=request.user.id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserEditProfile(request.POST, instance=user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form = UserEditProfile(instance=user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'edit.html', args)
```

Comment: Have you tried django-ipware (https://github.com/un33k/django-ipware) for getting user ip?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass `request` object into form directly. That's not the way it works. If you need to associate any `request` attributes to your model instances, you should do it in the views.

You could collect the `request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] which gives the IP info of the logged in user in the view and associate it to your`instance` in the view itself.

You could do this in your `form.is_valid()` method,

```
if form.is_valid():
    profile = form.save(commit=False)
    profile.ip_address = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
    profile.user = request.user
    profile.save()
    return redirect('profile')
```